# Suddenly Facebook API stopped working on Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

My code hasn't changed, it was working yesterday or so.

I can oauth, get the token but then doing the following:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += result;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me&access_token=xxxTOKENxxx", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Returns a NotFound WebClient exception: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Strange thing is that when pasting that same url on Chrome or IE it does work(PC).

Tried on Emulator and on 2 different real WP devices, even pasting the same url on the WP browser.

Feels like facebook is rejecting Windows Phone for some reason?

Anyone has an idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Can you paste the code into a desktop app and confirm it works from that?

Comment: Yes, works on any browser/machine except Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like there is a bug on Facebook being tracked

click here if you want to follow

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/367369176650486?browse=search_4fd82eadc62186861827790

after reading the link someone says graph.beta.facebook.com does work instead of graph.facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm its not you. WP7 sample from the SDK from GitHub is failing. ASP.NET sample is now returning an "Error occured in . Please try again later." error. As you noted, copying and pasting the URL into IE resolves and returned the expected JSON. Clearly something has changed.

Comment: Might be worth raising an issue on Connect.microsoft.com to investigate in case Facebook are playing dirty.